# How to use JSFiddle (JavaScript, HTML, Firebase)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, jsfiddle

I want to use JSFiddle to make it easier to provide help through stackoverflow.

I try to add following code:

```
<form method='post' action='' onsubmit="return onFormSubmitted()">
    <input type='text' name='Leerling' id='Leerling'>
    <input type='text' name='Opmerking' id='Opmerking'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

with this JavaScript code:

```
function onFormSubmitted()
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");
    var _leerling = document.getElementById("Leerling").value;
    var _opmerking = document.getElementById("Opmerking").value;

    var postsRef = ref.child("opmerkingen");
    var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
        leerling: _leerling,
        opmerking: _opmerking
    });

    var postID = newPostRef.key();
    var leerlingRef = ref.child("leerling").child(_leerling);

    leerlingRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {

        if( snapshot.val() === null ) {
            /* does not exist */

            var leerlingNummer = _leerling.substring(0,6).trim();
            ref.child("leerling").child(leerlingNummer).set({
                    "naam": _leerling.substring(7,33).trim(),
                    "klas": _leerling.substring(34,38)
            })
            ref.child("leerling").child(leerlingNummer).child("opmerkingen").push({
                "opmID": postID
            })

        } else {
            var leerlingPostRef = snapshot.ref().child("opmerkingen");
            leerlingPostRef.push({"opmID": postID});
        }
    });
}
```

and I added this external library: https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js

To begin with: the closing -tag is marked red in the editor.
Furthermore when running it, entering values for the 2 fields en clicking send I get the following message:

> {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}

Although this code actually runs fine. What am I missing on how to use JSFiddle?

Comment: tl;dr, please make a fiddle

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9e8nukk0/

Comment: @Jasper ... he is asking how to do it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the closing tag, JSFiddle looks for a well formed HTML document, which in your case is not, since the  tags are not closed, which is why the  tag has an erroneous closing tag, try to close the input tags and it should be resolved:

```
    <input type='text' name='Leerling' id='Leerling' />
```

Comment: tried that now but still get the same error? The form-closing tag is not red anymore however.

Comment: @jsfiddle I see you put the code in JSFiddle like I did. Can you run it without error?

Comment: No it doesn't work, I read up posts from some other users who say that the error goes away if you just do it in a plain HTML file, this error seems to only occur on jsFiddle. I haven't tried it myself but it would be great if you could try out by doing it in a plain file instead of jsFiddle.